# Angular delay fast http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

How can I delay an http request only if it completes under 1second.

first scenario:
- http request completes in 300ms, then we wait until 1 second ends.

second scenario:
- http request completes in 1 second and 300ms, then we DO NOT delay.

how to accomplish this with observables ?

Comment: Do you mind asking what is the scenario for calling an API and delaying it? While the answer below works, I am curious...

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko We had a problem with an http request that was sometimes faster than our loading animation and it wasn't pretty so we all agreed that waiting for the animation to finish was ok, having results from the http call as soon as possible wasn't highly important.

Comment: Ahhhh, so that was a UX issue basically. Makes sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`forkJoin`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) to wait until both Observables complete:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get(...),
  Observable.of(null).delay(1000),
  r => r // Use only the HTTP response
))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Here's a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/e2phrWHfrohkKAhYTbwg?p=preview) with a function that you might reuse [@Rachid Oussanaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1543885/rachid-oussanaa). I've also added a little benchmark to show the result with a fast (300ms) and a slow (1300ms) response.